# How to create a second bank transfer payment method?

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3.5-p1, payment-banktransfer

I'm using Magento 2.3.5-p1 and I need to create a second bank transfer method the same as the default from magento, because the client need to be able to choose between bank transfer in 30 days or in 1 day with a 2% discount.
I think there is no way to make that choice inside a payment method so I thought about creating one method for each option.
I know I need to create a custom module but I don't know how to create a payment method the same as the default from magento.

Best regards,
Rui Silva

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the below Url.

**http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2018/03/15/creating-custom-payment-method-in-magento-2/**